# parsing xml returned by web service response

Tags: c#, web-services, xml-parsing

I have read many questions on SO about this topic but I can seem to related to what I am trying to do. Basically I am calling a web service to return information about a Vehicle Identification Number (VIN). It returns an xml stream that looks like this:

```
<VINquery Version="1.0.0" Date="5/25/2003">
  <VIN Number="1HGES15501Lxxxxxx" Status="SUCCESS">
    <Vehicle VINquery_Vehicle_ID="23261" Model_Year="2001" Make="Honda" Model="Civic" Trim_Level="LX Sedan">
      <Item Key="VINquery Vehicle ID" Value="23261" Unit=""/>
      <Item Key="Model Year" Value="2001" Unit=""/>
      <Item Key="Make" Value="Honda" Unit=""/>
      <Item Key="Model" Value="Civic" Unit=""/>
      <Item Key="Trim Level" Value="LX Sedan" Unit=""/>
      <Item Key="Manufactured in" Value="UNITED STATES" Unit=""/>
      <Item Key="Production Seq. Number" Value="xxxxxx" Unit=""/>
      <Item Key="Body Style" Value="SEDAN 4-DR" Unit=""/>
      <Item Key="Engine Type" Value="1.7L L4 SOHC 16V" Unit=""/>
      <Item Key="Transmission-short" Value="5M OD" Unit=""/>
      <Item Key="Transmission-long" Value="5-Speed Manual Overdrive" Unit=""/>
      <Item Key="Driveline" Value="FWD" Unit=""/>
      <Item Key="Tank" Value="13.20" Unit="gallon"/>
      <Item Key="Fuel Economy-city" Value="30 - 32" Unit="miles/gallon"/>
      <Item Key="Fuel Economy-highway" Value="38 - 39" Unit="miles/gallon"/>
      <Item Key="Anti-Brake System" Value="Non-ABS" Unit=""/>
      <Item Key="Steering Type" Value="R&P" Unit=""/>
      <Item Key="Standard Seating" Value="5" Unit=""/>
      <Item Key="Optional Seating" Value="No data" Unit=""/>
      <Item Key="Length" Value="174.60" Unit="in."/>
      <Item Key="Width" Value="67.50" Unit="in."/>
      <Item Key="Height" Value="56.70" Unit="in."/>
    </Vehicle>
  </VIN>
</VINquery>
```

I want to take that data and parse it out for each key/value.
This is my code I am using the get the xml data:

```
private string baseURL = "http://ws.vinquery.com/restxml.aspx?accessCode=xxxxxx&vin=xxxxxxxxx";
private string reportType = "&reportType=2";

public XmlDocument ExplodeVIN(string strVIN)
{
   DataTable dt = new DataTable();

   string url = baseURL + strVIN + reportType;

   HttpWebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;

   XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
   using (HttpWebResponse resp = req.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
   {
     xmlDoc.Load(resp.GetResponseStream());
   }
   return xmlDoc;
}
```

After I get the xmlDoc I am not sure what to do next.

Thanks for your kind assistance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can parse xml to `Dictionary<string, string>` with Linq to Xml:

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
var items = xdoc.Descendants("Item")
                .ToDictionary(i => (string)i.Attribute("Key"),
                              i => (string)i.Attribute("Value"));
```

Usage:

```
string driveline = items["Driveline"];
```

Or

```
foreach(var kvp in items)
    // use key value pair
```

Comment: I dont understand your line: var xdoc = XDocument.Parse(xml). The parse method looks for a string. Where is the string xml coming from?

Comment: @Ryan that supposed to be service response string. If you have response stream, then use `XDocument.Load(stream)` instead

Comment: This seems to be working close...var items = xdoc.Descendants("Item").ToDictionary(i => (string)i.Element("Key"),
                                                                  i => (string)i.Element("Value")); results in an argument null exception and I am not sure why

Comment: @Ryan sorry, my bad. Key and Value are attributes, not elements. I have fixed code. Also you have not escaped ampersand in your xml for `Steering Type` key. Ampersand should be escaped as `&amp;`

Answer (score 3):

```
XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
XmlNodeList xmlnodelstTrack = xmldoc.GetElementsByTagName("Item");
foreach (XmlNode NodeObj in xmlnodelstTrack)
{
  //Do stuff with NodeObj.OuterXml

}
```

Comment: I do like this solution too. In my xml example would I pass the "Vehicle" node to get the Item node key/values? Or should I pass "Item" to get the key/values as I loop?

Answer (score 3):

There is another way that I usually use to deal with xml.

**Step 1:** Copy your xml string and paste as classes.

[image: Paste XML As Classes]

When you paste it, this code will be generated automatically:

```
        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
        public partial class VINquery
        {

            private VINqueryVIN vINField;

            private string versionField;

            private string dateField;

            /// <remarks/>
            public VINqueryVIN VIN
            {
                get
                {
                    return this.vINField;
                }
                set
                {
                    this.vINField = value;
                }
            }

            /// <remarks/>
            [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
            public string Version
            {
                get
                {
                    return this.versionField;
                }
                set
                {
                    this.versionField = value;
                }
            }

            /// <remarks/>
            [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
            public string Date
            {
                get
                {
                    return this.dateField;
                }
                set
                {
                    this.dateField = value;
                }
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
        public partial class VINqueryVIN
        {

            private VINqueryVINVehicle vehicleField;

            private string numberField;

            private string statusField;

            /// <remarks/>
            public VINqueryVINVehicle Vehicle
            {
                get
                {
                    return this.vehicleField;
                }
                set
                {
                    this.vehicleField = value;
                }
            }

            /// <remarks/>
            [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
            public string Number
            {
                get
                {
                    return this.numberField;
                }
                set
                {
                    this.numberField = value;
                }
            }

            /// <remarks/>
            [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
            public string Status
            {
                get
                {
                    return this.statusField;
                }
                set
                {
                    this.statusField = value;
                }
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
        public partial class VINqueryVINVehicle
        {

            private VINqueryVINVehicleItem[] itemField;

            private ushort vINquery_Vehicle_IDField;

            private ushort model_YearField;

            private string makeField;

            private string modelField;

            private string trim_LevelField;

            /// <remarks/>
            [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Item")]
            public VINqueryVINVehicleItem[] Item
            {
                get
                {
                    return this.itemField;
                }
                set
                {
                    this.itemField = value;
                }
            }

            /// <remarks/>
            [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
            public ushort VINquery_Vehicle_ID
            {
                get
                {
                    return this.vINquery_Vehicle_IDField;
                }
                set
                {
                    this.vINquery_Vehicle_IDField = value;
                }
            }

            /// <remarks/>
            [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
            public ushort Model_Year
            {
                get
                {
                    return this.model_YearField;
                }
                set
                {
                    this.model_YearField = value;
                }
            }

            /// <remarks/>
            [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
            public string Make
            {
                get
                {
                    return this.makeField;
                }
                set
                {
                    this.makeField = value;
                }
            }

            /// <remarks/>
            [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
            public string Model
            {
                get
                {
                    return this.modelField;
                }
                set
                {
                    this.modelField = value;
                }
            }

            /// <remarks/>
            [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
            public string Trim_Level
            {
                get
                {
                    return this.trim_LevelField;
                }
                set
                {
                    this.trim_LevelField = value;
                }
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
        public partial class VINqueryVINVehicleItem
        {

            private string keyField;

            private string valueField;

            private string unitField;

            /// <remarks/>
            [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
            public string Key
            {
                get
                {
                    return this.keyField;
                }
                set
                {
                    this.keyField = value;
                }
            }

            /// <remarks/>
            [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
            public string Value
            {
                get
                {
                    return this.valueField;
                }
                set
                {
                    this.valueField = value;
                }
            }

            /// <remarks/>
            [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
            public string Unit
            {
                get
                {
                    return this.unitField;
                }
                set
                {
                    this.unitField = value;
                }
            }
        }
```

**Step 2:**
Deserialize your xml string to this generated class.

```
public T DeserializeXML<T>(string xmlContent)
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
    MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xmlContent));
    return (T)serializer.Deserialize(memStream);
}

....
string resultXml = resp.GetResponseStream();
VINquery resultObject = DeserializeXML<VINquery>(resultObject);
```

Now you can easily manipulate and filter your result.

P.S.: You have to remove special chars (&) in your xml string because it causes a problem when you try to paste it as classes.

Comment: Any tips for using this method when the response it 10Mb i.e. extremely long?